# Create SQL parameters programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlparameter

Another annoying one for me but probably something simple.

I have a number of possible where clauses for a query based on user input, my question is how can I add these programmatically?

For instance:

```
wherequery = @"WHERE fieldname = @p_FieldName AND ";
if (txtValue.textLength > 0){
    wherequery += "fieldname2 = @p_FieldName2 AND ";
}
query = @"SELECT * FROM tabe" + wherequery;
sql = connection.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandText = query;
```

How would I go about doing the parameters for that?  I've tried ArrayLists, Dictionaries and a few other methods but can't find a way of doing it.  Ideally I'd want to do something like this:

```
SqlParameter[] sqlparams;
wherequery = @"WHERE fieldname = @p_FieldName AND ";
if (txtValue.textLength > 0){
    wherequery += "fieldname2 = @p_FieldName2 AND ";
    sqlparams.Parameters.Add("@p_FieldName2 ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtValue.text;
}
query = @"SELECT * FROM tabe" + wherequery;
sql = connection.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandText = query;
sql.Parameters.Add(sqlparams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small alteration to your code, which should hopefully point you in the right direction:

```
    sql = connection.CreateCommand();    
    wherequery = @"WHERE fieldname = @p_FieldName ";
    sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_FieldName ", "some value for fieldname"));

    if (txtValue.textLength > 0){
        wherequery += " AND fieldname2 = @p_FieldName2 ";
        sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p_FieldName2 ", txtValue.text));
    }
    query = @"SELECT * FROM tabe" + wherequery;

    sql.CommandText = query;
```

Comment: You've changed the parameters of the `Add` method? I'm mainly a web dev guy, but shouldn't this be `AddWithValue`? And how would this change anything?

Comment: Sorry, missed out the instantiation of a SqlParameter object. I've made an appropriate edit.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than programmatically adding the parameters, add them all, but include NULL conditions. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tabe
WHERE fieldname=@p_FieldName 
AND (@p_FieldName2 IS NULL OR fieldname2=@p_FieldName2)

sqlparams.Parameters.Add("@p_FieldName2 ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = null;
if (txtValue.textLength > 0){
    sqlparams.Parameters("@p_FieldName2").Value = txtValue;
}
```

Here, if the text length of `txtValue` is 0, then the `@p_FieldName2` parameter is set to `null`.

Then in the SQL Query the following will ignore the `fieldname2=@p_FieldName2` if the value is NULL:

```
@p_FieldName2 IS NULL OR
```

Comment: interesting idea but this would cause additional load on the server to process the query, and this server is already on its last legs :(

Comment: Voted up, I don't see how this would add additional load.  If anything, it's more efficient.  You've got a single query with one execution plan, rather than several permutations that must be parsed.

Comment: ok suppose you have 30 possible clauses, thats 30 null values, also what if you need to use the same field in different ways like a date field?

Comment: Well, in that case, maybe dynamic parameters is a better route for you.  It's certainly more flexible if you've got complex logic about how parameters get used.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<string,object>` where the string portion is the key and the object portion is the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of different possible fields to filter on, you're not getting away from coding them all, in one manner or another.

You could create a class to handle the string building. I stole this idea from work. =)

In pseudocode, it'd basically look like this:

```
Class WhereObj
{
  //whatever container you want to use to hold the params
  //you could also create a params class and have a list of param objects
  //it'd basically be a constructor and two properties

  private Params(,)

  Public void AddParam(fieldname, value)
  //adds param to Params

  Public string ToSQLString() 
  //loops params and builds string (use stringbuilder!)
  //ex: "where FirstName= 'Neo' and MatrixSequelsSucked = 'true'"
}
```

This should be a real easy class to code - probably under 50 lines. You should definitely create your own object to handle this, *especially* if you have to do this in multiple places. You could just write a function if it's only in one place, but I think it's a little cleaner to separate it out into an object.